# Building phone gap app for Android failing

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

When trying to build my phone gap app for android using

```
sudo phonegap build android
```

it fails with this error:

```
:compileDebugJava
/Users/youssefsami/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Developer/Mobile Apps/UzuConvert/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/inappbrowser/InAppBrowser.java:120: error: cannot find symbol

                                || Config.isUrlWhiteListed(url)) {
                                         ^

  symbol:   method isUrlWhiteListed(String)

  location: class Config

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

1 error


FAILED



FAILURE: 
Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.

> 
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.



* Try:

Run with 
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with 
--info or 
--debug
 option to get more log output.



BUILD FAILED


Total time: 5.607 secs


/Users/youssefsami/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Developer/Mobile Apps/UzuConvert/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^

Error code 1 for command: /Users/youssefsami/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Developer/Mobile Apps/UzuConvert/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/youssefsami/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Developer/Mobile Apps/UzuConvert/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/youssefsami/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Developer/Mobile Apps/UzuConvert/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: /Users/youssefsami/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Developer/Mobile Apps/UzuConvert/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I tried setting the java_home to the java alias in lib exec but still nothing. Any ideas on what maybe causing the problem?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem running Ember-Cli-Cordova

Answer (score 24):

It's because your InAppBrowser plugin is out date and probably out of sync with a newer version of the Cordova Android platform than when you first installed the plugin. I was getting the same issue with cordova-android@4.0.0 and 0.5.3 of InAppBrowser.

Fix is to first remove plugin

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Then add it again (it should reinstall with the latest version the cordova CLI has in my case it grabbed 0.6). You can check the version in the RELEASENOTES.md in the plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/ folder.

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

You will need to remove the android platform and re-add it before building again so it doesn't keep the old version of the plugin.

```
cordova platform rm android
```

and

```
cordova platform add android
```

Now build again and the error should have gone.

EDIT: I just noticed at the top of your question you are using phonegap. Since you tagged with cordova (and thats what I use) I answered with cordova commands, but I'm guessing almost the same process applies with Phonegap.

Comment: This worked, although the plugin had been renamed to `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

Comment: I found that explicitly setting the version to `@1.0.1` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem with cordova-android@4.0.0
Thank's JDawgg your solution's better than mine, but if someone still have the bug you can use cordova-android@3.6.4 like this :

```
cordova platform remove android
```

then

```
cordova platform add android@3.6.4
```

you must have android 4.2.2 sdk installed

Finally

```
sudo phonegap build android
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is using [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) and came across the same problem, [martijnwalraven](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5336#issuecomment-144473246) suggests removing the older version of `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` and add the most recent one:

```
$ meteor remove cordova:cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
$ meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.0.1
```

This did the trick for me!